# For what values the real parameter t is a matrix diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

[image: matrix]

What to do with number 25 in the matrix?

Comment: Have you tried finding the eigenvectors?

Comment: How ? Is  equal or not ?

Comment: You need to guarantee that each eigenvalue's algebraic and geometric multiplicities are equal.  So if $t=1$, then $\lambda=1$ better have three eigenvectors associated to it, if $t\neq1$, then 2.

Comment: To clarify Tyroshis answer: a triangular matrix always has all eigenvalues along the diagonal.

Comment: please explain: if t=1 then.....  otherwise, then....

Comment: If t=1 all the three diagonal elements are 1. Otherwise only two will be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix is diagonalizable if the sum of $\dim \ker (A - \lambda I)$ over all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$ is $n$.

When $t = 1$, the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$.  However, $\dim \ker(A - 1 I) < 3$, so $A$ is not diagonalizable.

However, if $t \neq 1$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $t$.  $\dim \ker (A - tI)$ is $1$.  We then note that $\dim \ker (A - tI)$ is $1$ whenever $t \neq 24$, and is $2$ when $t = 24$.

Thus, we find that $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $t = 24$.

Comment: thanks a lot :) a great use and educational to me

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking the $\checkmark$